# Generic mapper instead of having numerous individual mappers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` with `Razor` and `Autofac` for dependency injection.

I am thinking of creating a generic mapper.  Currently I am using `AutoMapper` for the mapping between my domain and view model.  It can be any mapping framework, but I am using AutoMapper .

Here is my `IMapper` interface:

```
public interface IMapper
{
     object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);
}
```

I then have an IBankMapper interface that implements this IMapper interface.  The reason why I did it like this is because I can have many different mappers.  Using dependency injection I can know what instance I can inject.  So for IBankMapper I will inject BankMapper, ICategoryMapper I will inject CategoryMapper.

`IBankMapper` interface:

```
public interface IBankMapper : IMapper
{
}
```

`BankMapper` class:

```
public class BankMapper : IBankMapper
{
     static BankMapper()
     {
          Mapper.CreateMap<Bank, EditBankViewModel>();
          Mapper.CreateMap<EditBankViewModel, Bank>();
     }

     public object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
     {
          return Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, destinationType);
     }
}
```

As the program grows so will the mapper classes.  Is there a way that I can create a generic mapper, one that can be used in the whole application?  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question. AutoMapper *is* a generic mapper...

Comment: I'm trying to lesson my mapper classes.  I have BankMapper, AccountTypeMapper, ProductMapper, ApplicationMapper, etc.  I'm wanting to try and create 1 mapper class (if this is possible) which accepts a source and destination class.  Something like TSource and TDestination.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no need for you to create any mapper classes at all.

All you need to do is be sure that you call `Mapper.CreateMap` at the beginning of your application. You can then use `Mapper.Map` to do your mapping.

Typically, I create a static class with a single method to handle the creation of my Maps. It looks something like:

```
public static class Transformers
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Bank, EditBankViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EditBankViewModel, Bank>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Account, EditAccountViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<EditAccountViewModel, Account>();

        // And so on. You can break them up into private methods
        // if you have too many.
    }
}
```

I then call that method inside Global.asax do ensure that it runs when necessary. In any other spot in my application, I'm free to call `Mapper.Map` for any of the configured mappings:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Transformers.Register();
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with a unit test for mapping a view model to domain model and how you would implement this in your controller?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are creating these interfaces to be able to mock AutoMapper in your unit tests. You can simply use `IMappingEngine` from AutoMapper for this purpose.

Your classes would have a dependency on `IMappingEngine` which would be injected. `IMappingEngine` has the same methods as the static class `Mapper` to map your objects.

In your composition root you would configure the mapper and register the mapping engine with the DI container.

Something like this:

```
// composition root:
Mapper.CreateMap<Bank, EditBankViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<EditBankViewModel, Bank>();
builder.Register(Mapper.Engine);

// your classes:
class YourClass
{
    public YourClass(IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said, Automapper is already a generic mapper. If you're worried about the direct dependency to automapper in your code, you can hide it behind a little facade, e.g.:

```
public interface IMapper
{
    TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source);
}
public class MyMapper :IMapper
{
    public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
    }
}
```

This can also help you to model the mapper as an injectable dependency

Comment: No need to do this. AutoMapper already provides such an interface!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I didn't know that, thanks for your remark. That said, some people don't want to depend on 'externally defined' interfaces, this solution could still be used in those cases.

Comment: I agree: If the dependency on the interface of a concrete auto mapper is a problem, your facade interface helps and is the way to go. However, it doesn't look like that is the OPs problem.

Comment: @jeroenh: Can you supply some source code of a unit test mapping the view model to domain model and how you implement this in your controller?  It is much appreciated.